# File links in Asp.NET web forms site

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an old Asp.NET web forms site that I am working with to get certain file links to work in newer browsers. The file links are currently structured like this:

> file://server/somefolder/somefile.pdf

If I attempt to open a link like this in newer browsers like Chrome or Edge, it gives me an error of "not allowed to load local resource." I have read articles that say to structure your link like this:

> file:\\\//server/somefolder/somefile.pdf

This works when I embed such a link in a plain html file. However, when I attempt to use such a link in web forms, it rewrites the link so that the end result looks like the first link.  I know that there are flags in Chrome and Edge that could allow for opening local resources, but our security team would probably come for me with pitchforks for the suggestion. Is there a way in Webforms to force it to not do this with file links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to a network folder, this should still be allowed.

When using "file" as you are, then you are in effect 100% by-passing the IIS server, and are asking the browser to open that file local. As noted, this is currently not allowed for your local files (on drive c:), but is supposed to be allowed for network folders. this is somewhat of a surprise this was EVER allowed.

In fact, I am surprised that your 2nd format works. It MAY well work if you type in that network path to open a file, but from a browswer link, you simple not going to have much luck with this approach. Quite sure fireFox, and Mozzilia don't even allow this.

For chrome (or edge), you can add a add-in, but with browser secuirty, I would not bet much on this approach.

There are two solutions I can think of:

Are the path names to a known network folder? If yes, then add a virtual directory to the web site that points to that folder. That way, valid URL's from the server can be used.

(you would have to update the URL's you have now - hopefully in a database).

So, you could add a virutal folder to IIS, and have it point to

MyServerFiles.

So then your valid URL would now be:

```
 https://localhost:44392/MyServerFiles/somefile.pdf
```

And thus URL's to that folder would now be valid, and would require the web based URL to link to those files.

Another way? If the web server is on the same network, then simple have the code behind read the file as raw file bytes and stream it out. This is only a few lines of code, and thus once again, any file on the network could be opened, (as long as the web server has use of those network paths - and thus if you running IIS local, or at least on a server that is part of your network, then this approach would probably be the best, since then you don't have to map a virtual folder to the web site. In fact, this approach enhances security, since no valid URL's from the web site have to exist, nor will exist.

Remember, code behind in your web site is plane jane windows path names - not mapped URLS. Thus that code quite much ignores IIS security, and you simple read the file from that network share, and then write it out to the client side.

Since the network path is allowed by all users, then I suspect does the web server ALSO have use of that path? If the web site is hosted, then of course this will not work.

In other words, in code behind (which does not use URL's), then it could read the file, and stream it out to the client side. This would be a longer trip for the file and data but should allow this to work.

So, say you have a button (or hyper link). Hopefully this is some kind of say grid or whatever. (have to assume the file list is generated somehow).

so, say a simple grid view like this:

[image]

the button click code is this to download:

```
Protected Sub cmdDownLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Dim sFile As String = gRow.Cells(0).Text

    Dim sInternalFile = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/" & sFile)
    ' now stream file down to browser
    If File.Exists(sInternalFile) Then

        Dim strConType As String = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(sInternalFile)

        Dim binFile As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(sInternalFile)
        Response.ContentType = strConType
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + sFile)
        Response.BinaryWrite(binFile)
        Response.End()

    End If

End Sub
```

Now in above, I grab the file from the grid, and used UpLoadFiles. But, UpLoad files could be ANY plane jane network path.

the value part in above is we use a plane jane windows path name, read the file, and send it to the browser.

So, the virtual folder idea, or a raw binary read of the file would work if the web server is running on your same network.

Comment: I assumed opening them from the server would ultimately be the best course of action, but wanted to be sure. I went with option 2. Thanks.